# Security and Apache Methods

Tags: htaccess, apache, security, httpd.conf, hacking

I occasionally get annoying POST requests but one lately caused a 500 error. Not a biggie really, but it got me thinking.

My site does not have but one form. Outside of this, POST should not exist for any request. I can control this using .htaccess. So I started planning some additional security measures.

GET and HEAD should of course be allowed always.

POST only for the one form.

*Other than that, WHAT Apache Methods should be allowed and which should be blocked?*

I would imagine blocking PUT, DELETE, and TRACE at the least.

I do not expect an answer on all of the Methods of course. Just based upon your knowledge and experience. If you have a resource to help detail this, that would be great!

Here is a list of all of the METHODS (for reference):

GET / HEAD / PUT / POST / DELETE / CONNECT / OPTIONS / TRACE / PATCH / PROPFIND / PROPPATCH / MKCOL / COPY / MOVE / LOCK / UNLOCK / VERSION_CONTROL / CHECKOUT / UNCHECKOUT / CHECKIN / UPDATE / LABEL / REPORT / MKWORKSPACE / MKACTIVITY / BASELINE_CONTROL / MERGE / INVALID